# How do i resolve 'Uninitialized string offset:' error in TinyButStrong

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I was successfully download the merged spreadsheet document but it gives me these errors instead of the merge values. Why is that and how should i resolve it ?

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2 in /.../tinybutstrong-opentbs/tbs_plugin_opentbs.php on line 1832

Notice: Undefined index: in /.../tinybutstrong-opentbs/tbs_plugin_opentbs.php on line 1832
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your OpenTBS version ? And can you give you line of code that makes this happen. It is probably something with OPENTBS_CHART.

Comment: @Skrol29 version is 1.9.2 . The line 1832 gives this code ' $i['ctype'] .= $ctype[($Ext[2])]; '. If i commended this code and run the merge it works..wondering why is that? how should i perform the merge without commenting the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug that occurs when you open a LibreOffice template from a stream (using fopen() for example).

The only consequence is for the Mime header when the merged result is downloaded using OpenTBS.

So commenting this line of code is a correct work around.
This bug will be fixed in the next OpenTBS version 1.10.1.